# Exponentiation in a Ring

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

The identity $a^{(b+c)} = (a^b)(a^c)$ holds when $a,b,c$ are real numbers.

Now, consider a commutative ring $\mathcal{R}(+,\times)$ with unit.
Under what conditions on $\mathcal{R}$ does $a^{(b+c)} = (a^b)\times(a^c)$ hold for all $a,b,c \in \mathcal{R}$?.

Perhaps assuming $a \neq 0$ and $b+c \neq 0$ makes things simplier?

It seems like the statement is true in $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ but not true in $\mathbb{Z}_Q$ (integers modulo $Q$) even if $Q$ is prime.
Perhaps we need $\mathcal{R}$ to have characteristic $0$ then?

It would be nice to also understand intuitively the necessary conditions on $\mathcal{R}$.

Comment: How do you define $a^b$ in a ring?

Comment: Arbitrary rings do not have an exponentiation operation; you can define $a^n$ for positive integers $n$; and for *units* you can define it for negative integers. But in general you cannot even extend it to rational exponents.

Comment: For $b=u/v\in \Bbb{Q},a\in k$ any field $k$ then $a^b$ has some kind of meaning : a root of $x^v-a^u\in k[x]$, so $a^b$ is an element of the algebraic closure of $k$, but this root of $x^v-a^u$ is not unique, up to a choice of root then $a^{b+c}=a^b a^c$ holds. It is specific to $\Bbb{R}$ that (for $a > 0$) we can choose a specific root and obtain that $a^{b+c}=a^b a^c$. When letting $b\in \Bbb{R,\not \in Q}$ we are really using that $\Bbb{R}$ is complete and that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense.

Comment: $a^b = a \times \cdots \times a$ where $a$ appears $b$ times

Comment: I guess $b$ times doesn't actually make sense in a general ring